# How to make colorbar on Contourf in a semilog scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar, contourf

So I'm creating contour plots of electric fields for some school work, and the variations are pretty extreme (1e-6 to 1e+8), and I want to show the contour in a logarithmic scale. The issue is that there are both positive and negative electric fields, and the Matplotlib.Ticker.LogLocator destroys the negative values, and I want all the values plotted on a continuous colormap. I cannot find any easy way to set a ticker to do semilog scaling and other solutions have been eluding me.

Here is my code thus far:

```
def plotEField2D(data_in, ax, fig, field='Ey', xlim=100, ylim=100, num_levels=20, 
                 contours=False, num_lines=10):

    electric_data = data_in.electric
    ax.set_xlim(-xlim, xlim)
    ax.set_ylim(-ylim, ylim)

    ax.set_title('2D ' + field + ' Contour')
    ax.set_xlabel('x (nm)')
    ax.set_ylabel('y (nm)')

    e_data = pd.pivot_table(electric_data[['x','y', field]],
                            values=field, index='y', columns='x')

    e_data = e_data.interpolate().fillna(0)

    mymin = np.min(e_data.values)
    mymax = np.max(e_data.values)

    e = ax.contourf(e_data.columns, e_data.index, e_data.values, num_levels,
                    cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, locator=matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator(),
                    norm=matplotlib.colors.SymLogNorm(linthresh=1000, linscale=0.1, vmin=mymin,
                                                      vmax=mymax), vmin=mymin, vmax=mymax)

    fig.colorbar(e, ax=ax, format='%.0e', extend='both')

    if contours:
        e = ax.contour(e_data.columns, e_data.index, e_data.values, 
                              num_lines, colors='k', linewidths=1)
```

I'm attempting to implement the SymLogNorm in my Contourf plot, but, as you can see in the image, the contourf is screening out values less than 0 even though I'm passing in the SymLogNorm parameter. I'm not super familiar with SymLogNorm, so I'm hoping it's something basic that I'm just missing.

[image: My current output]

Why is the SymLogNorm not creating the color gradient that extends into the negative like in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/userdemo/colormap_normalizations_symlognorm.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-colormap-normalizations-symlognorm-py)? I've checked that mymin and mymax are negative and positive respectively, so I know it's not that.

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Simply using `matplotlib.ticker.SymmetricalLogLocator` [(docs)](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.SymmetricalLogLocator) instead of the `LogLocator` should solve this, I believe?

Comment: That did it! I'm glad it was that simple.